# Application Reopen Event - Cocoa/ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have application1 calling application2 using

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:....
```

Now, when Application2 opens, I want to do some operation on windows load. This is fine when I open the application first time. I can do my logic in awakeFromNib event.

If the application 2  is minimized (In dock) after open, it opens from the doc when application1 calls application2 again and none of initWithWindow, awakeFromNib, WindowDidLoad is triggering.

Is there any window event which gets triggered when opened from first time or reopen from minimized state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an `NSApplication` delegate you will receive [various notifications/calls](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you can use for that. For example could you use

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification
- (void)applicationDidResignActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

You may only have to check first start vs. becoming active using a variable in your app delegate. Also, `DidBecomeActive`should be called also on startup.

Comment: Thanks. I was checking this event in ViewController but this event is available in AppDelegate. I have handled this by using Notification.